# how to prevent user from using space more than one time with preg_match?

Tags: php, drupal, preg-match

i want a php code to prevent users in the username registration field in drupal from using more than one space.

The usermame should not contain more than one space.

please help

Comment: Is it, more than one space? Or more than one significant space? (i.e "User Name" vs "Username ") Where "Foo Bar" would be acceptable, but "Foo Bar Foo" would not -- and "Foo Bar " and "Foo Bar" are considered the same, and "Foo Bar Foo " would still be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is to use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

Indeed you want to accept usernames like `'Adam Sinclair     '` with space at the beginning or the end. This function will remove them.

Then by using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$pattern = '/( ).*( )/';
$username = 'Wrong Username containing more than one space';
if ($ret = preg_match($pattern, $username))
    echo 'Wrong username\n';
else if ($ret !== false)
    echo 'Good username\n';

$username = 'Adam Sinclair';
if (preg_match($pattern, $username))
    echo 'Wrong username\n';
else  if ($ret !== false)
    echo 'Good username\n';
```

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

However another alternative would be to use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
if (substr_count($username, ' ') > 1)
    echo 'Wrong username\n';
else  if ($ret !== false)
    echo 'Good username\n';
```

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

> substr_count — Count the number of substring occurrences

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need preg_match for this. This can be accomplished with [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) like this:

```
if( substr_count( $username, ' ' ) > 1)
    echo 'Wrong username';
```